# Memcached failing after PHP upgrade

Tags: php, session, memcached, amazon-elasticache, php-5.6

I have been using memcached and I upgraded from PHP 5.4 to 5.6 and now it is failing to connect and store.

I have:

```
ini_set('session.save_handler', 'memcached');
ini_set('session.save_path', 'serverAddress:11211');
session_start();
```

I have also tried tcp:// before the server address, but no luck there.

In the error log, I am getting the following errors:

- PHP Warning:  session_start(): Write of lock failed
- PHP Warning:  session_start(): Unable to clear session lock record
- PHP Warning:  Unknown: Failed to write session data (memcached).
  Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is
  correct

I guess something changed in the versions of PHP. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

**Note: I am using Amazon Elastic Beanstalk for the web server and ElastiCache for the memcached**

**What I Have Tried**

1. Used a config file with:

   ```
   files:
     "/etc/php.d/setup.ini":
       mode: "000644"
       owner: root
       group: root
       source: https://s3.amazonaws.com/path/to/file.ini
   ```

Inside of the ini file is:

```
    [php]

    session.save_handler = memcached
    session.save_path = 'memcached.server.path.cache.amazonaws.com:11211'
```

2. I have tried using `session_write_close()`
3. I have tried using tcp:// before the server path
4. I have also tried using memcache instead of memcached as the
   handler.

Comment: I just tried using a .ebextensions .config file to change the master value instead of using ini_set in the page, but that does not seem to work either and throws the same errors.

Comment: I have the same problem. It happens very rarely, but it happens. It seems to be a bug in PHP: https://github.com/php-memcached-dev/php-memcached/issues/269

Comment: Did you ever find a fix for this issue?